# Cannot remove read-only from USB drive

Tags: usb-drive, read-only

I **cannot paste** anything into my **USB drive** although I used [that solution](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/12/19/how-to-fix-read-only-usb-pen-drive-in-ubuntu/) 
but the problem is there. I cannot paste anything inside. How do I fix this?

> Error while copying to "USB drive Name"
>   The destination is read-only

The destination is read-only

Comment: Read only is often a symptom of a failed or about to fail drive.

Comment: Try copying via terminal. I think I found a bug in Nautilus producing that error some time ago but didn't report it because I wasn't able to reproduce it reliably. If copying via terminal works, you're probably experiencing the same bug.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Apparently a restart did the work. Who knows what the problem was...

Comment: Next time I will consider copying via terminal, good idea @UTF-8!

Comment: @Skemelio Tell me when it occurs again, maybe we can narrow the bug down.